Error getting Access_Token in Spotify Api_React-Native-App
I'm having trouble getting the access token to Spotify Api: Error getting the token [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400] .
Here is the code to see if you can help me to solve the problem.Thanks in advance.
config/adapters/async-storage.ts
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export class AsyncStorageAdapter {
    static async getItem (key: string) : Promise<string | null>{
        try{
            return await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    }

    static async setItem (key: string, value: string): Promise<void>{
        try{
             await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error(`Error setting item ${key}- ${value}`);
        }
    }


}

config/api/spotifyApi.ts
import {API_URL_TOKEN} from '@env';
import axios from 'axios';
import {AsyncStorageAdapter} from '../adapters/async-storage';
import { getToken } from '../../actions/token/getToken';


// 1. Create a configured axios instance
export const spotifyApi = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL_TOKEN,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
});

// 2. Middleware for adding the access token to requests

spotifyApi.interceptors.request.use(
    async(config) =>{
        let token = await AsyncStorageAdapter.getItem('token');
        
        if(!token){
            await getToken();
        }
        if(token){
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        console.log('config', config);
        return config;
    },
    error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
)

actions/token/getToken.ts
import {CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, API_URL_TOKEN} from '@env';
import { AsyncStorageAdapter } from '../../config/adapters/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';
import { TokenResponse } from '../../infrastructure/interface/token.response';




//function to obtain the token

export const getToken = async() =>{
    console.log('Client_id', CLIENT_ID);
    console.log('Client_Secret', CLIENT_SECRET);
    console.log('url_token',API_URL_TOKEN);
   
    const body = new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    });
    const params = body.toString();


    console.log('params', params);
    try{
        const resp = await axios.post<TokenResponse>(API_URL_TOKEN, params, {
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        });
        console.log('resp', resp);
        const token = resp.data.access_token;
        await AsyncStorageAdapter.setItem('token',token);
        return token;


    }catch(error){
        console.log('Error getting the token', error);
        throw new Error('Error getting the token');
    }
}

Hi people. I'm having trouble getting the access token to Spotify Api: Error getting the token [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400] .
Here is the code to see if you can help me to solve the problem.Thanks in advance.
